# ReSharper и VS: страдает перерисовка интерфейса

Tags: c#, интерфейс, resharper

Подлагивает интерфейс Visual Studio с установленным R#

[image: Артефакты в интерфейсе]

В дебаге вообще ужас

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто решал такую проблему?

UPD:
Решение проблемы нашел такое: перевел VS на GPU, решарпер не причем

Comment: не используй решарпер :)

Comment: @Grundy она реально спасает. думаю проблема в  крякнутом решарпере. попробуйте обновить решарпер

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, а возможно нужно просто добавить оперативной памяти

Comment: @SeniorAutomator решарпер лицензионный, только сегодня установил 2016.3

Comment: @Grundy 80% занято при запущенной студии, сама она занимает ~250мб

Comment: @Grundy альтернатива - Visual Assist, но пока лицензию не дали, может есть еще альтернативы? мне нужно немного, переименование, подсветка синтаксиса (стандартная не нравится), подсказка импорта при наборе

Comment: @ВикторПегий, то что Вы требуете это уже давно стандартные фичи самой VS. Ставить ReSharper или VA для этого не обязательно. Подсветка: поменяйте под себя, как вам удобно в настройках. Тем более, судя по скринам, VS у Вас 2015-ая. Там это ещё удобней сделали. Just `Ctrl+.`

Comment: @AntonKomyshan в стандартном интерфейсе не нашел, как изменить подсветку отдельно метода, отдельно класса, отдельно события, и т.д.

Comment: @ВикторПегий, ну в таком случае - да, просто в настройках это не сделать. Для этого можно посмотреть в сторону [SemanticColorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer), например.

Comment: По мне, так VsVim полезней R#) но если очень хочется, у JetBrains есть такое руководство https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.3/Speeding_Up_ReSharper.html

Comment: Решил проблему: перевел VS на GPU, решарпер не причем